# How to write an python script to interact with a remote service with http

Tags: python, http, post

I am on the hook to write a Python script to interact with a remote web server with http. Here is the server (name: username; password: passw0rd), basically I will need to upload an image to the remote server, and printout its analysis output.

I have almost zero knowledge on Python network programming and really have no idea how this can be worked out. Could anyone shed some lights on where should I start to write such a script? I can find the following http post request from `chrome`, but just have no idea how to proceed further:

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: 34.65.71.65
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3185
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3cwcmQ=
Origin: http://34.65.71.65
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryUPXn3eOKoasOQMwW
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Referer: http://34.65.71.65/post
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7
```

This is the `Python` script I am writing right now:

```
import requests

# defining the api-endpoint
API_ENDPOINT = "http://34.65.71.65/post"

# your API key here
username = "username"
pwd = "passw0rd"

path = "./kite.png"
image_path = path
# Read the image into a byte array
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()

# data to be sent to api
data = image_data

# sending post request and saving response as response object
# r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, auth=(username, pwd), data = data)
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, auth=(username, pwd), data = data)

# extracting response text
pastebin_url = r.text
print("The pastebin URL is:%s"%pastebin_url)
```

but somehow it triggers the following issue:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

And here is another trial:

```
import requests

# defining the api-endpoint
API_ENDPOINT = "http://34.65.71.65/post"

# your API key here
username = "username"
pwd = "passw0rd"

path = "./kite.png"

with open(path, 'rb') as file:
    body = {'foo': 'bar'}
    body_file = {'file_field': file}
    response = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, auth=(username, pwd), data=body, files=body_file)
    print(response.content) # Prints result
```

Comment: And I even cannot find a corresponding entry for the "image" data. Am I missed anything here?

Comment: The HTTP protocol is fairly well documented so browsing the RFC might be a good starting point (hint: what you posted above are only the request headers, the data are in the request body). This being said, your best bet for HTTP client code is the `python-requests` package (https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) - it doesn't alleviate the need to first understand the HTTP protocol but it makes coding a breeze.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for the comment. I updated the question. Could you please take a look? Thank you!

Comment: You should have opened a new question instead...  And you have to check your target API's doc to find out what it expects (content type etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an HTTP request in Python is very easy thanks to the requests API. Uploading a file requires you to read it first and then upload it in the body of a POST request.

The broken PIPE error often occurs when the server closes the connection before the client could send all the data. Which is often due to an inconsistency between the content size announced in the headers and the real content size. To resolve this, you should read the file as 'r' or 'rb' (if it is binary) and use requests API files kwargs to send the file.

```
import requests

with open(file.name, 'rb') as file:
      body = {'foo': 'bar'}
      body_file = {'file_field': file}
      response = requests.post('your.url.example', data=body, files=body_file)
      print(response.content) # Prints result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried this method but what I can get is the html source code on that page... I updated the question.

Comment: @lllllllllllll You should change the fields in my example to match your needs

Comment: I opened a new question on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736856/python-http-post-request-connection-aborted